# Original 3D Array and lists changing when changing copy of it

Tags: java, jagged-arrays

I know the title sounds a little weird, but let me try to explain you.

I have programmed a small state machine, and I'm trying to implement a blind search to final state (Determined by the user). So far, I've been able to generate all possible states for a numbered 2x2 grid. Each state is defined by this:

```
static List<State> states = new ArrayList<State>();

public class State {
    int info[][][];                             //Información del éstado (Número almacenado en x, y, z posición)
    HashMap<String, State> vecinos = new HashMap<String, State>();      //Lista de vecinos e instrucción para llegar a ellos desde el estado actual
    boolean valido;                             //Bit de validez
    boolean visitado;                           //Bit de visitado

    public State() {
        this.info = info;
        this.valido = true;
        this.visitado = false;
    }

    public boolean equals(State s) {
        boolean iguales = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < face; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
                    if (this.info[i][j][k] != s.info[i][j][k])
                        iguales = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return iguales;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String ret = new String(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < face; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                ret = ret + "\n";
                for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
                    ret = ret + " " + info[i][j][k] + " ";
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;

    }
}
```

Now, as you can see I have a HashMap inside each state. This HashMap is the one I'm supposed to use for the blind search, but heres my problem:

```
public State genSt(State estado, instrucciones inst) {
    State nxtSt = estado;
    int[][][] toswap = new int[face][rows][cols];
    int[] place0 = new int[3];

    switch (inst) {
        case arriba:
            boolean val = checkvalidity(estado, inst);
            if (val) {
                place0 = find0(estado);
                toswap = estado.info;
                int swap = estado.info[place0[0]][place0[1] + 1][place0[2]];

                toswap[place0[0]][place0[1]][place0[2]] = swap;
                toswap[place0[0]][place0[1] + 1][place0[2]] = 0;
                nxtSt.info=toswap;

                nxtSt = repeated(nxtSt);
                if (nxtSt != null) {
                    estado.vecinos.put("arriba", nxtSt);
                    nxtSt.vecinos.put("abajo", estado);
                    nxtSt.valido = true;
                    System.out.print("\n ARRIBA \n _________ \n" + nxtSt.toString());
                } else
                    System.out.print("\nREPEATED ARRIBA\n");
            } else return null;
            break;
...
default:
            System.out.print("InstrucciÃ³n invÃ¡lida");
    }
    //estado = nxtSt;

    return nxtSt;       //Regresa estado generado
}
```

But when I change the values of nxtSt it also changes the values of estado, and the rest of the elements in the list states. So everyone has the same hashmap and I can't do my search.

Do you know how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I tried to implement a manual deep copy for the info, but I think I did the same just in more lines, because it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
public int[][][] genNxSt(State original){
    curInfo = new int[face][rows][cols];

    for(int f =0; f<face;f++){
        for(int r=0; r<rows; r++){
            for(int c=0; c<cols; c++){
                curInfo[f][r][c] = original.info[f][r][c];
            }
        }
    }
    return curInfo;
}
```

Comment: When you do 'State nxtSt = estado;', nxSt is just another reference to same data in estado. You will need to implement clone on your state object that does a deep copy of the array and the hashmaps it contains. See java.util.Arrays for the basic array copying, but I think you'll have to do a manual deep copy of the hashmaps (there's a nice google library to do this, but just do a .clone() on the hashmap won't be sufficient).

Comment: So, since I can't do a clone, I must implement a function todo a deep copy and activatet instead of 'State nxtSt=estado;'?

Comment: That line is just giving you a new name (reference) nxSt that points to same underlying data. You want to do 'State nxSt = estado.clone();', but you fill have to implement the Clonable interface and the clone method to the proper deep copy. Assuming you are changing the HashMaps inside the array, you'll have to implement a deep copy for that as well, a .clone() on a HashMap doesn't give a deep clone IIRC.

Comment: Actually all I need is copy the int [][][]info of the current state to the copy, the rest is added further in the code

Comment: You are essentially passing the same data to both classes, not copying it. for achieving a true copy in an easy way, you can use an intermediate variable of same data type, like `int comodin= estado[i][j][k]` and then `nxtST[i][j][k] = comodin`. By the way, I love the sentence "REPEATED ARRIBA", it's hilarious

Comment: It keeps doing it, I also tried clone library but it didn'twork